# Facebook integration "error occurred try again later"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to connect my app with facebook. I created app on facebook and this is my code:

```
private void CheckAuthorization()
        {
            string app_id = "appID";
            string app_secret = "appSecret";
            string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "markhagan.me video tutorial" });
            }
        }
```

When page loads login Pop Up is shown. When i login with email of user who created facebook app everithing works perfect. But every other different login results in message "error occurred try again later". Can someone tell me where i m making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the application Sandbox Mode is set to "Off"